# Rails - Sort items and change title according to sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `table` which has animals. I have just 2 `species`: dog and cat.

I want to sort items in view and add a `h1` (like: Cats Names , Dogs Names ) when animal species come to the other one. I can do this by putting dogs(`@dogs)` and cats(`@cats`) to different variables in the `controller` but I want to achieve it in `view` if it is possible.

I can sort animals in my view like:

```
 <% @animals.sort_by(&:specy).each do |animal| %>
       // Here I need to add a h1 when species change
      <%= animal[:name] %>
  <% end %>
```

How I want to sort and show in my view is:

**Cat Names** 
Bella
Kitty
Lilt
**Dog Names** 
Charlie
Luna
Max

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it is better to use two queries, you will probably save yourself a nice chunk of code and it will be nicer and easier to read. But if you really want to solve it in the views, you can do something like this:

In your controller

```rb
# other conditions are omitted
@animals = Animal.order(:specy)
```

In the view

```
<% last_specy = nil %>
<% @animals.each do |animal| %>
  <% if last_specy != animal.specy %>
    <h1><%= animal.specy %> names</h1>
    <% last_specy = animal.specy %>
  <% end %>

  <%= animal[:name] %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by` method to group an collection based on an attribute.

```
<% @animals.order(:specy).group_by(&:specy).each do |animal_species, animals| %>
  <h1><%= animal_species %> Names</h1>
  <% animals.each do |animal %>
    <%= animal.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Source https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by

You might also want to use sql `group` along with `GROUP_CONCAT` function to achieve better performance.